# RapidMiner FP-growth operator not returning any results

Tags: text-mining, rapidminer

i'm running into a problem with the fp-growth operator in rapidminer. i'm processing about 20 text files that are all in all <1MB in size. i used the process documents operator and within that tokenize, filter stop words, transform cases, generate n-grams, and filter tokens. from there i used the numerical to binominal operator. up until this point everything works fine, but when i run the fp-growth operator it just processes indefinitely with no result. i tried tweaking the min support parameter, but to no avail. would you have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this? i'd really appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

FP-Growth is an algorithm to find Frequent Item Sets within a number of transactions that contain multiple items. In your scenario, the items are probably the words occurring in the text, while each text is a transaction.

Unfortunately the problem of frequent item sets is exponentially: Say you have a frequent item set that contains the items {A, B, C}, that means that there are enough transactions that contain all three items. But that also means that all the subsets are frequent as well, because the subset {A, B} is at least contained in all transactions that contain {A, B, C}. So if {A, B, C} is frequent, {A, B}, {B, C}, {A, C} and {A}, {B} and {C} as well. The number of sets is (2^n) - 1. So for a set of four items, we already have 15 subsets, for five 31 and so on.
So the question is: What makes a set frequent and why might there be so many frequent sets that RapidMiner takes so long to compute them all?

The most important factor is of course the min_support. This defines the threshold in percent of in how many transactions a set must occur to be frequent. If you increase the min_support towards 1, then there will be much less item sets and the computation will be faster.
However, don't get tricked by the "find min number of itemsets". If this is checked, RapidMiner will try to always find the specified minimal number of itemsets and will automatically lower the min_support if it couldn't find any. My advice: Switch it off.

Another thing you should make sure is, that the right value is recognized as "positive", so as indicator that this item is part of the transaction. If you used a Numerical to Binominal operator before, this is "true". So you should enter "true" into the positive_value parameter of RapidMiner. This parameter is only visible in expert mode. If you are not in expert mode, a line will show up below the parameters telling you, that "4 hidden expert parameters" are available. You can click on the line to switch to expert mode.

In your specific scenario, where you are getting your 'transactions' from text files, you will have special problems:

1. You will have thousands of attributes, especially if you generated NGrams like in your case. A high number of attributes also will result in a massively increased runtime.
2. If you don't remove frequent words by applying a reasonable pruning in the Process Document operator, words that occur pretty frequently will be exploding the number of frequent item sets. Say you didn't filter Stopwords, then the words "a", "the", "is" will occur all over the place, causing the other frequent words to co-occur with them. So the frequent set {A, B, C}, will always be extended to {A, B, C, a, the, is} so we now have 2^6 -1 subsets instead of just 7...

Hope this helps!